# looking for react datatable/grid lib supports styled-components

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, datatable

I need react table/datagrid lib that supports styled-components
that I can to style table in styled(table) HOC
also I would like to inject custom styled-component rows, filter, pagination, overlay.
And of-cause it should be up-to-date maintainable library.

I checked **react-table** v6 there is styling callbacks, v7 looks good but still in @alpha.

**Rectabular-table** supports styled-components and looks nice but quit dead last publish 10+ months ago.

**griddle-table** is also quite OK but also last publish year ago. (I still not sure about how to use styled-components with it)

**react-bootstrap-table2** is nice stylish table out-the-box but I think there still no styled-component support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just looking for a table library? I used material-ui together with styled-components for most of my work. They have pagination and sorting examples. And it is by Google, so you know the library will have a high chance of always being maintained. 
https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/

It is interoperable with many other libraries as well 
https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with AG-Grid. It has lot of features for styling tables. Link below:-
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/